# Azure Search Using just a Filter without a search expression

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

How do you make a search in Azure Search using just a filter and no search expression.

The method indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync() requires a search expression and the SearchParameters object.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the search expression to null or "*" to match all documents. This is in the [SDK documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.search.documentsoperationsextensions.search.aspx#M:Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentsOperationsExtensions.Search(Microsoft.Azure.Search.IDocumentsOperations,System.String,Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.SearchParameters,Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.SearchRequestOptions)):

> searchText
>
> Type: System.String
>
> A full-text search query expression; Use null or "*" to match all documents. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn798920.aspx for more information about search query syntax.